# Number of 3 digit numbers with distinct digits

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-verification, recreational-mathematics, decimal-expansion

I need to find the number of 3 digit numbers without repetition (distinct digits).

**MY ATTEMPT:**
All 3-digit numbers:$100,101,102,103,.....,999$ (i.e. $1000$ numbers)

**But we need to exclude following types of numbers**

> _11,_22,_33,..._99 type (8*9 numbers = 72 numbers because the first digit should not start with 0 or be similar to the other digits)
>
> 1_1,2_2,..,9_9 type (9*9 numbers =81 numbers)
>
> 11_,22_,...,99_ type (9*9 numbers =81 numbers)
>
> 111,222,333,...,999 type (9 numbers)

**Required number of numbers** = $1000-81-81-72-9=657$

But the actual answer is $648$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: All 3-digit numbers are not 1000 to start with.

Comment: @peter.petrov Where did I say all 3 digit numbers are 1000?

Comment: You can also think it this way: You have 9 ways to choose the first digit (it cannot be zero), 9 ways to choose the second (it can be zero but it cannot be the same as the first one) and 8 ways to choose the third one (it can be zero but it cannot be the same as the first or second one). Total: $9 \times 9 \times 8 = 648$.

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano Thanks.That's nice too :-)

Comment: @ZOZ Here: "MY ATTEMPT: All 3-digit numbers:100,101,102,103,.....,999 (i.e. 1000 numbers)"

Comment: @peter.petrov I've no idea what you are trying to say.The question has been answered well already.See Leo's answer below.

Comment: @ZOZ I know that but you asked me so I responded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just forgot to eliminate numbers ending with double $0$. Once you do this your method yields $900-81-81-81-9=648$.

Comment: Thanks a lot :-)! That was a careless mistake on my part :-P :-D

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to necessarily prove that all of your exclusions are complete.